# Working with Arrow Keys in a WPF Textbox (C#)

Tags: wpf, textbox, keypress, arrow-keys

Is there any way to catch the Up/Down arrow keys in a WPF TextBox (`System.Windows.Controls.Textbox`) and allow them to alter the text? I've read about overiding the `ProcessCmdKey` method for a Windows Forms TextBox (`System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`), and it worked fine, but that `TextBox` is not nearly as flexible as the WPF one. Is there a similar method to accomplish this without having to use the old Windows Forms TextBox?

For my example, I have a TextBox that has a numeric text-mask. I want to be able increase/decrease the numeric value by using the up and down arrow keys.

Comment: I like how this question was asked, specifically mentioning that Windows.Forms was NOT wanted/needed.  The answer below was spot on.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could add event handlers to KeyUp and/or KeyDown, if that doesn't get what you need, using PreviewKeyUp and/or PreviewKeyDown should.

Comment: Wow...I feel dumb for not thinking of the PreviewKeyDown method...worked like a charm.

Comment: don't feel dumb :)  the whole Preview* set of events was non-obvious to me for a while...